# Use the same Layout from Client Project in Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have BlazorWebAssembly project with Server project.
How can i use MainLayout.razor in Server project (for example : by change password or something else..)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways off the top of my head:

- Put that file in a shared project that both blazor apps use, just like the default Shared project in the wasm template
- Copy that file with a build task to your secondary project. You can set that up in your .csproj file.

here's a basic sample of the second:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\myserverapp\shared\*\**\*">
      <Link>Pages\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```